# handling huge arrays in python

Tags: python, memory, virtual-memory

My program runs a simulation which requires huge objects to store the data in. The size of the blob is larger than 2-3GB. Even though I should have anough memory in my MBP, python (Python 2.7.3 on Mac OS X, from ports) cannot seem to use it all, and the system gets totally frozen.

To save the status of the simulation, I use pickle, but it also doesn't work for too large objects, it seems as if pickle would duplicate the objects in the memory before dumping them...

QUESTION: is there a standard library which can handle huge python data structures (dict, set, list) without keeping them in the memory all the time? Alternatively is there a way to force python to run in virtual memory? (I'm not very familiar with numpy, would it help me in this situation?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using 64 bit Python right?

Comment: Have you tried not storing all the data in an object, and instead keeping it as a file on the disk and reading it piece by piece and doing your processing in steps?

Comment: I know that it doesn't help you, but I just had an example of mine yesterday night with a list of tuples 6G large, python was able to handle no problem, MacOS 10.8 here. So it's not rally python's issue I guess. My machine has 20G total RAM.

Comment: @OdayMansour: yes, that is the alternative solution that I rewrite the code. But I want to avoid it if there is an already existing solution for the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes 64bit

Comment: @favoretti: well I have only 8GB and it seems that the largest object I can allocate is around 6GB in the Real Memory. (while Activity Monitor claims that python is using some 19GB virtual memory which can't be possible...)

Comment: I suppose things like NoSQL databases in lines of MongoDB or alike are known to you and not the thing you're looking for?

Comment: By the way, what is your data? For example, you're mentioning "simulations" and a "list" data structure. You don't store integers in list, don't you? array.array would be much more memory efficient for numbers because list with int elements is an array of pointers to int objects (being Python objects, they have overhead themselves: pointers to types, refcounts), and array.array (or numpy.array) is just a plain array of fixed-size numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the 64bit version of Python and still run into problems with `pickle` or other built-in modules, you can store the Python objects in an object-orientated database instead. We're working with large objects (~10GB) here everyday and use [ZODB](http://zodb.org/) for that. It's not the fastest but gets the job done.

I also hear that [dobbin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dobbin) might be a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this ZODB. My last hope before posting this question was cPickle, but it seems that it has the same problem like the standard python implementation.

Comment: ZODB seems to have solved my issue, although I will be truely happy only tomorrow when the calculation ends successfully. :)